# Objective-c garbage collection

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, garbage-collection

If garbage collection is not required:

```
- (void) awakeFromNib{

//Create the NSStatusBar and set its length
statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSSquareStatusItemLength] retain];
...
```

Do I have to release that? And if I do, would that be in a finalize method or dealloc method?

If garbage collection is required, then is the retain call above ignored automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, since you have retained the object you must release it. The place where you would release it is the `dealloc` method. And yes, when garbage collection is enabled it ignores all retain/release calls. Read the memory management rules [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html) for more information.